# How to resize page markers on the vertical and horizontal edges of Paint?

Tags: microsoft-paint

How do I resize the vertical and horizontal markers for the Paint page? I know they should be located in the middle of the vertical or horizontal edge but they are so small that I struggle to find them.

In below screenshot I've circled the markers I'm referring to:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot resize those markers *only*.

[Scaling up the whole Windows interface](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027860/windows-10-view-display-settings) does increase those markers a bit, but it also scales up the rest of your interface.

If you find it hard to click those markers you can also resize the page via `File` ➡ `Properties` (or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>):

[image]